# Explanation of For loops in Python 2.7

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am running Python 2.7.3. on Xubuntu. My questions is a request of an explanation of "for" loops. I  was reading a lot of different explanations but I still don't comprehend why does the for loop work the way it does (especially in following example). 
I am using a simple code as an example. The code counts lines.

I have opened a .txt file with e-mail list and other information (here: http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt) and I am interested in parts starting with "From:".

```
for line in fhand:
 if line.startswith ("From:"):
   print line
```

I think I understand that I could translate this loop as kind of *For every "part/x/line" of object "fhand" do following:* if line start with "From", print line.

Mine confusion is that I can basically input an "x" instead of line or whatever I want and it will still work well. How does the for loop understands that I want it to count only lines? What is the "countable" part in here and how can I imagine it? Basically I would like to understand more deeply why the following code can work as I believe it can help me to construct other similar codes in the future.

Thank you for any effort put into answering this.

Comment: Line is just a variable name. You can take almost every name you want for a variable. You should read some books for beginners.

Comment: It does not matter what you call the variable. Its not like "if it's called 'name', let's return lines, and if it's called chars, let's return characters". A file object is an iterator of lines, so that's that it iterates over. Period.

Answer (score 0):

`fhand` is an [iterable object](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) of strings.

`line` is hence a single string member in that object.

You can name it whatever you like, it is still regarded as a string.

Comment: `fHand` is a more than likely a file object.

Comment: I just noticed that in the OP's question "I have opened a .txt file with e-mail list and other information" :)

Answer (score 0):

fhand is an array/list/collection/file handler/whatever of iterable items - it doesn't matter what it is, but it's a collection of them.

If it's a file handler, a file when read is usually read line by line, hence why the for loop works on a per line basis.

The for loop is basically a "for each thing in list".  I think the "line" variable is what's throwing you.  That could be named anything… e.g.:

```
for x in fhand:
    if x.startswith("From"):
        print x
```

"Line" is JUST a variable, it has no bearing whatsoever on HOW the code works, it's just a friendly named identifier.